# aws cli command to create quicksight datasource with input json and credentials parameter

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

I am able to create quicksight data-source using aws cli command with inputjson. input json contains all the paramenters that are required to create datasource like RDS username/pwd. I can't hardcode the username/pwd within json, so I want to pass all other parameters via json and only credentials separately. is that possible?

`aws quicksight create-data-source --cli-input-json file://./create-data-source.json`

Comment: how can I pass credentials block separately along with input json to create a data-source?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of json and the shell script that will go inline with:

```
aws quicksight --account-id --credentials{CredentialPair{Username="string",Password="string"}}
```